# GetAzVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection Status for multiple Vnet gateways

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have a requirement to gather the information of connection status for multiple virtual network gateways between multiple resource groups

Let's say

I have one vnetgateway in rg1 and vnetgateway in rg2.

I established a connection to vnet1tovnet2 and vice versa between both virtual network gateways. The connection is done
Now I have a command called Get-Azvirtualnetworkgatewayconnection -name ( **here I have to give the connection name**) - resource group name $rg

Now my question here is that. I want to fetch those connection names itself and pass it to Get-Azvirtualnetworkgatewayconnection -name as a parameter or variable.

I don't find a command for that. As to know the name of the connection i need to go to portal,fetch those details and then embed in powershell code. This can be done for one or 2
But i have multiple vnetgateway and multiple connections

Hence getting those connection names and then knowing the connection status (either connected or disconnected) will help me.

Anyone has any idea on this?
Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Can someone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well , this is solved

I had to just use  `get-azvirtualnetworkgatewayconnection -resourcegroupname 'myresourcegroup'`

And now the output of this code is stored to a variable called $vnet let's say

Now, I used a foreach loop

```
Foreach ($v in $vnet.name){
Get-Azvirtualnetworkgatewayconnection -name $v -resourcegroupname 'myresourcegroup'}
```

That's it. This just pulls out the status of the connection details and i have then added `select-object Name, resource group name , connectionstatus` at the end to filter out the required properties for me as an output. That has done the job easily.

Thank you.

Posting this as it might be helpful for someone.

In case if someone is looking out for a whole script on this. Please comment down
I can update it here. Thanks.